# Dealing with a list of GUID objects inside Python

Tags: python, list, guid

I am trying to shift a list in Python,
but I still have the message error : 
"Message: 'Guid' object has no attribute 'append'".
I know that a GUID is an object identifier. I guess I need to convert the GUID list to a list with integer items, like [0, 1, 2, 3, ..., 50]
But I don't know how to do that.
Here is the part of my code which doesn't work :

> ```
>    self.line2 = rs.AddLine(self.shape1, self.shape2)
>    self.line2.append( self.line2.pop(0) )
> ```

I hope I was enough clear, and thank you for your help.

Paul

Comment: Please post more of your code. Starting from the `Guid object`.

Comment: My guess is that AddLine returns a GUID and not a list of GUID :)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to convert a UUID into a list of integers is to use the `fields` field. This returns the UUID as a list of 6 integers.

```
In [10]: from uuid import uuid4

In [11]: x = uuid4()

In [12]: x.fields
Out[12]: (919787229L, 42311L, 17040L, 154L, 62L, 226429597314256L)
```

Comment: I don't really see how this does answer the OP question!

Comment: His only concrete query was " I guess I need to convert the GUID list to a list with integer items, like [0, 1, 2, 3, ..., 50] But I don't know how to do that." which is what I'm attempting to answer.